# Iterating over a dataframe twice: which is the ideal way?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, sankey-diagram

I am trying to create a dataframe for Sankey chart in Power BI which needs source and destination like this.

| id | Source | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Starting a | next point b |
| 1 | next point b | final point c |
| 1 | final point c | end |
| 2 | Starting a | next point b |
| 2 | next point b |  |
| 3 | Starting a | next point b |
| 3 | next point b | final point c |
| 3 | final point c | end |

I have a dataframe like this:

| ID | flow |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Starting a |
| 1 | next point b |
| 1 | final point c |
| 2 | Starting a |
| 2 | next point b |
| 3 | Starting a |
| 3 | next point b |
| 3 | final point c |

I tried doing by iterating over the dataframe twice like below:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for j, r in df.iterrows():
    if row['ID'] == r['ID']:
        if (index + 1 == j) & ("final point c" not in row['flow']):
            df['Destination'][index] = df['flow'][j]
        elif "final point c" in row['flow']:
            df['Destination'][index] = 'End of flow'
```

Since it is iterating over the same dataframe twice, when the records are huge, it is taking a lot of time to process.

Is there any better way to do this? I tried looking at the all similar questions, but couldn't find anything that relates to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `groupby`+`shift` and a bit of masking:

```
end = df['flow'].str.startswith('final point')
df2 = (df.assign(destination=df.groupby('ID')['flow'].shift(-1)
                               .mask(end, end.map({True: 'end'}))
                 )
         .rename(columns={'flow': 'source'})
       )
```

output:

```
   ID         source    destination
0   1     Starting a   next point b
1   1   next point b  final point c
2   1  final point c            end
3   2     Starting a   next point b
4   2   next point b            NaN
5   3     Starting a   next point b
6   3   next point b  final point c
7   3  final point c            end
```

Alternative with `combine_first` to fill the NaNs:

```
end = df['flow'].str.startswith('final point').map({True: 'end', False: ''})
df2 = (df.assign(destination=df.groupby('ID')['flow'].shift(-1).combine_first(end))
         .rename(columns={'flow': 'source'})
       )
```

output:

```
   ID         source    destination
0   1     Starting a   next point b
1   1   next point b  final point c
2   1  final point c            end
3   2     Starting a   next point b
4   2   next point b               
5   3     Starting a   next point b
6   3   next point b  final point c
7   3  final point c            end
```